# gtm datalayer in laravel view effects the other page some ajax doesn't work 500 internal server error

Tags: ajax, laravel, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I have the shopping cart at page add product cart I have added the datalayer when I click to proceed to checkout, it shows 500 internal server error , and some ajax not working , 
when I paste the datalayer without any blade code it works fine. 
here are the screenshots to demonstrate my issue.

I have tried replacing my laravel code with simple datalayter object and it works fine.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

ohooo,, my mistake was that, I was using the same header for every page in laravel blade, when i dynamically generate the dataLayer for one page in HEAD, it works fine because that dynamic data is available for that specific page, but not on other pages and I am using same header for every page, thats why it creates the corrupt javascript with errors in other pages which blocks the further running of Javascript and page shows 500 internal Server error.
I just replaced the header and place page specific dataLayer in its respective pages, so the problem solved.

Thanks Buddies.